# Switching Between VS Code and VS 2015

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-code

I am a single developer starting out on an ASP.Net Core MVC project with Angular 2. I used the Steve Sanderson template [VS Angular 2 Template](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/) which works well in Visual Studio 2015. Up until now I have been developing the structure, and my understanding, of ASP.Net Core, Entity Framework Core, Identity, WebPack, NPM etc. and working in VS 2015 has been great.

Now I am moving on to learning and developing the client side of the project which in places will involve Angular 2. Already I am finding VS 2015 a bit clumsy and would like to try Visual Studio Code.

Is it possible to switch between the two on the same project? It would be great to be able to develop Angular components in VS Code and switch back to VS 2015 for any C# work. Writing code in VS Code I imagine would be fine, but what about the debugging/webpack building side of things?

Any experience or suggestions very welcome. Thanks.

Comment: I found it quite easy. I was doing an android project with a webview, and I wrote the java in android studio and the webview portion in vscode. I used typescript for the javascript and it had it compile every time I saved a typescript file. I then just had to re-run the android project in the emulator. For you it should be a similar process.

Comment: We tried this also but had problems that VS or VS code was locking files in node_modules. And then typescript transpiling didn't work suddenly.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully setup my Visual Studio 2015+ ASP.NET project on VSCode.

I've created an **gulpfile** that handle the build for me:

1. It starts an IISExpress instance.
2. Refresh my browser on **razor** code change.
3. And automatically rebuild my application when I change C# code.

You can find the **gulpfile** on my [project's Github](https://github.com/saintplay/Eva-360/blob/3ece4e83fb2ef4fd892a400918de23314ef2e592/Eva360/gulpfile.js)

**Important note if you are going to switch between VSCode and Visual Studio:**
When you want to create a new file, I strongly suggest you to do it in Visual Studio.